# How to check multiple conditions using Vue Router global navigation guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In a vue 3 application which is using pinia, I want to achieve the following

1. redirect a user to the sign in page whenever a user is not authenticated
2. redirect a user to a verification page if the user authenticated but not verified
3. redirect a user to dashboard if the user is authenticated & verified

At the moment I have been able to redirect unauthenticated users to the sign in page and redirect them to the dashboard when authenticated by writing my router index.js file like this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/signin",
            name: "signin",
            component: () => import("../views/SignIn.vue"),
        },
        {
            path: "/verify",
            name: "verify",
            component: () => import("../views/Verification.vue"),
            meta: { needsAuth: true }
        },
        {
            path: "/dashboard",
            name: "dashboard",
            component: () => import("../views/UserDashboard.vue"),
            meta: { needsAuth: true }
        }
    ]
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.needsAuth && localStorage.getItem('accessToken') == null) next('signin')
    else next()
})

export default router
```

and here is the method that handles signin

```
const loginUser = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "https://some-api-url/login",
      signin.value,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.data.accessToken);

    // redirect home
    router.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    error = error.response.data.message;
    alert(error);
  }
};
```

Now my challenge is the signin endpoint I am calling only return an access token but the dashboard endpoint return the verified status. How can I achieve redirect unverified users to the verification page?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to redirecting an authenticated but unverified user to the verification page by adding pre-route guard to the `dashboard` part like this

```
{
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "dashboard",
    component: () => import("../views/UserDashboard.vue"),
    meta: { needsAuth: true },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('verified') == "false") next('verify')
    }
}
```

So what happens is the global guard will check if the user is authenticated while the pre route guard will check if the user is verified. It works now but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it as I have more routes that need the user to be verified.

Isn't it possible to do it inside the global guard as well? Funny I am asking a question inside a supposed answer